# change multiple key names using reduce and preserve position

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. Is it possible to run `reduce` only once to change the key names? In the example below, I run the `reduce` function twice. How this can become more efficient? Can this be done with one iteration?

```
    const newArrayOfObj = rows.map(row => {
        row = Object.keys(row).reduce(
            (a, key) =>
             ({
                ...a,
                [key === 'redirects' ? 'clicks' : key]: row[key],
            }),
            {},
        );

        row = Object.keys(row).reduce(
            (a, key) =>
             ({
                ...a,
                [key === 'tags' ? 'external impressions' : key]: row[key],
            }),
            {}
        );
        return row;
    });
    return newArrayOfObj;
}
```

Comment: Use switch/case in your `reduce` callback instead

Comment: This shouldn't be closed. OP is iterating over an object's key twice, and performing some replacements. The question is if that can be done in one iteration. It's not unclear.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why they close the question.